# Network not functional after converting Virtual Machine to Physical

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtualization

I have a Ubuntu server instance running on a virtual box machine which is running on a Windows 10 machine.  I converted the VM to physical and put it in a new machine and booted it up.  It boots fine but there is no functioning network.

To make the conversion I booted into clonezilla in the VM and cloned the virtual drive to an external hard drive. Then on the new machine I did the same to clone the external drive to the internal drive on the new machine.  It boots fine but there is no internet connection.  When doing ifconfig the adapter is docker0.

I've tried a fresh install on a different drive on the same machine and the networking worked good. The adapter there is eno1 and has a different mac address than the docker0 adapter on the cloned install.

I've done some googling and haven't been able to find anything that would seemingly fix this and I'm at a loss at how to get the networking functional again.

Edit to add requested info: Ubuntu version is server 18.04.
See attached pic for id addr output:

[image: ip addr output]

Edit 2: Picture of hangup during boot:

[image: Picture of hangup during boot]

Comment: Add to your question above the complete output of `ip addr` on the bare-metal server...and clearly explain exactly which release of Ubuntu you are running. Virtual interfaces are NOT the same as real interfaces, so "docker0" not working seems like expected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addition of `ip addr` was already useful, we see none of the interfaces is up or configured. If the following doesn't help please consider also adding the output of `networkctl` so you can check which are actually managed.

As it seems the system most likely has a network config not matching the adapters you have on the bare metal machine. Read [netplan.io](https://netplan.io/) for more but a config matching your screenshot would be placed in e.g. `/etc/netplan/51-my-interfaces.yaml`

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: true
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
```

After that is in place run `sudo netplan apply` and your interfaces should try to come up and try to get dhcp addresses.

Comment: That worked to get networking going however during boot it now gets hung up for a bit on a message that says "a start job is running for Wait for Network to be Configured".   See the pic in edit 2 of the original post.  It makes booting take 2-2.5 minutes.

Comment: Well, I was guessing by your screenshot :-) That delay is the dhcp on the interface that isn't really active. Just check after your system is up which of the two actually got network and dhcp and then remove the other one from the file here. That should resolve your boot delay as right not you are telling it to wait on dhcp on both.